# How to prepend a tr at the very first of the table according to the size of td's in the first TR of HTML using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a tr as the very first children of the tbody with checkboxes, Here I have tried but didnt get result.

```
var ss = $('tbody tr')[0]
        var trLen=$(ss).find('td').length;
        //alert(trLen);
        var cnt=0;
        $('<tr>').prepend
        for(var k=0;k<trLen;k++) {
                $('<td>').prepend
                $('<input />', {
                    type : 'checkbox',
                    id : 'col_'+cnt,
                    class : 'dt-checkboxes',
                    value : name
                }).prependTo($(this));

                $('</td>').prependTo($(this));
                cnt++;

        }
        $('</tr>').prependTo($(this));
```

HTML

```
<tbody><tr style="height:15.0pt;"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="dt-checkboxes" value="">
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1" rowspan="2">Total general</td>
          </tr>
</tbody>
```

Help me to get the solution
Thanks

Comment: can you make a table structure , what you actually want?

Comment: What I actually want is, I need the prepend the checkboxes inside each TD's similar to the above mentioned tr > td at the very first child of tbody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/8w05u9oa/1/

```js
$('table tbody').prepend('<tr></tr>');
$('table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td').each(function(){
 $('table tbody tr:nth-child(1)').append('<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>');
});
```

```css
table, tr, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi I dont have th in my table

Comment: Yeah got it , Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO**

```js
var ss = $('table tbody tr:first td');
console.log(ss.length)

//get number of td in first row of table
var pre = '<tr>';
for(var i=0;i<ss.length;i++){
 pre+= '<td><input type="checkbox" id="col_'+i+'" class="dt-checkboxes" value="name"/>&nbsp;</td>';
}
pre+='</tr>';
$('table tbody tr:first').before(pre);//add this tr before first tr of table
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
<tbody><tr style="height:15.0pt;">
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;1</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;2</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;3</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;4</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;5</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;6</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;7</td>
<td class="td_0_1" colspan="2">Total general</td>
          </tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt;">
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;1</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;2</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;3</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;4</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;5</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;6</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;7</td>
<td class="td_0_1" colspan="2">Total general</td>
          </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

You can do something like this. get all `td` and use [jQuery .each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and then [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to that `td`.

Comment: No not like this, I need the checkboxes to be the first child of tbody. Checkboxes in the sense, In First TR each TD should have checkboxes

Comment: only on first tr? not rest?

Comment: okay will explain clearly. I need to add a new TR as the first child of tbody where the each td has checkboxes